# Using setMethod to creating a method for a list of an object type

Tags: r

I've created a method `myMethod` that accepts the object `myObject` as an argument. I would like to be able to pass this method a list of `myObject`. I could just use a `for` loop to pass each object individually, but I'd much prefer to use R's built in capability of handling functions.

I've created a method like so:

```
setMethod("myMethod",
      signature = c("myObject"),
      definition = function(obj, ...){
          "some code"
      })
```

I have a default method shown here:

```
myMethod <- function(obj, ...){
    print("Generic base function; does nothing.")
    obj    
}
```

This works perfectly fine when I send it an object of that type. Say I have a list of myObject saved in listOfObjects.

If I do:

```
> myMethod(listOfObjects[[1]])
```

Everything works as expected when "my code" is executed. However if I instead send it a list of the same objects it hits my default method:

```
> myMethod(listOfObjects[1:10])
```

I get:

```
[1] "Generic base function; does nothing."
```

Is there anything I can do to get `myMethod` to easily run on every object in my list? My list could be very large so I'd like to use R's built-in vector functions rather than using a 'slow' `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your phrase *R's built in capability of handling functions* is very ambiguous.
In my understanding, it is `lapply`.
So simply:

```
lapply(objs, myMethod)
```

If you want a function that takes a list of objects, you can define one:

```
setMethod("myMethod",
      signature = c("list"),
      definition = function(objs){
          lapply(objs, myMethod)
})
```